# Count distribution in which the mean is equal to the standard deviation?

Tags: variance, expected-value, standard-deviation, poisson-distribution, count-data

I have a data set with counts that exhibit the sample property that

$$\hat \sigma_x \approx \bar x$$

which is to say that the sample standard deviation (with Bessel's correction) appears to approximately equal the sample mean. Actually, I have multiple sets of data which exhibit this property, which is what motivated me to ask this question. This property reminded me of a [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) which has the property that

$$\text{Var}[X] = \mathbb{E}[X] = \lambda$$

in the population.

Is there a parametric family of distributions for natural numbers (including zero) that instead satisfies

$$\sqrt{\text{Var}[X]} = \mathbb{E}[X]$$

under any choice of parameters?

---

- Actually, excluding zero from the support is OK b/c I would just create a mixture with a Dirac $\delta$ distribution.
- I have quickly checked that the geometric distribution and negative binomial distributions do not satisfy this property.

Comment: It's usually more constructive to identify a family based on knowledge of the data generation process, because this moment criterion doesn't pin down the family.  For example, take any family with multiple parameters, equate your moments, and solve: *voila.*  Example: set $p=1-1/r$ in the [Negative Binomial family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution). Here's a simulation: `r <- pi;
x <- rnbinom(1e5, r, 1 - 1/r);
c(mean(x), sd(x))`

Comment: @whuber I had this concern, and I had unsuccessfully tried to word my way around it, and your comment affirms that it is warranted. It is a wait time distribution (count of days till event). After accounting for the effects of weekdays vs weekends using dummy variables leaves a collection of residuals with an approximately uniform power spectrum. I doubt that narrows things down to a specific distribution. So fitting different distributions after equating moments might be the best option. Or just allowing the separate parameters that happen to fit to very close to the same value.

Comment: Have you considered the exponential distribution?

Comment: @dimitriy I really like the exponential distribution, but its support is the non-negative real numbers whereas the question above asks for a distribution over the non-negative integers.

Comment: Your "count of days until the event" sounds like a positive *real* random variable that has been rounded up to an integer, suggesting you could investigate rounding an Exponential distribution.  Provided its parameter is not too small, the rounding will not appreciably change the quadratic relationship between its mean and variance as the scale varies.  In fact, writing $\theta$ for the scale parameter for such a variable $X,$ $\operatorname{Var}(X) - E[X]^2 - \theta = 0,$ entailing $\operatorname{Var}{X}/E[X]^2=O(1)$ for $\theta\gg 0.$

Comment: @whuber Thank you for raising that observation. Yes, I think in my model there is no reason I couldn't use an exponential distribution. Indeed, I could model the rounding as part of the data generating process in the MCMC simulation. For example:

$$X \sim \text{Exponential}(1)$$
$$Y := [X]$$